# Problems with migration from swift2 to swift3 with ranges

Tags: count, range, swift3

I have strings and determine the ranges of indexes. I will need later for instance   `.last` `.count` for these ranges. How should I initialise the range for string to be able to get functionality `.last` `.count` for these ranges  (that is obvious in swift2 but not in swift3) ?

For example, I am often using the `.count` for range of string in my code in swift2, like this

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let myRange = str.rangeOfString("Hello")

let myCountOfRange = myRange.count
```

Now it is not possible to do this in swift3

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let myRange = str.range(of: "Hello")

let myCountOfRange = myRange.count // type index does not conform to protocol strideable
```

Comment: Give an example of your Swift 2 code that you're trying to convert to Swift 3.

Comment: @vacawama I have added an example

Comment: Actually you know the number of characters in `Hello` already before getting the range, for the position in `str` there is `lowerBound` and `upperBound`

Comment: @vacawama It is simplification. When I have arrays of ranges for a string and  to go back to substrings of these ranges and calculation of characters for these substrings is a mad thing which is not an improvement in swift3 in comparison with swift2. Why to make things more complicated then it was before?  What is the price for this ? !!

Comment: I know, it seems crazy.  If you do `print(myRange)` you get `Optional(Range(Swift.String.CharacterView.Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 0, _core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x000000010f9798b0), _countAndFlags: 17, _owner: nil)), _countUTF16: 1)..<Swift.String.CharacterView.Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 5, _core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x000000010f9798b0), _countAndFlags: 17, _owner: nil)), _countUTF16: 1)))`.  There's a lot in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift3, to find the size of a range you can do:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let myRange = str.range(of: "Hello")

let myCountOfRange = str[myRange!].characters.count
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works.

Alternatively:

```
let myCountOfRange = str.distance(from: myRange!.lowerBound, to: myRange!.upperBound)
```

Both require access to the original collection (ie. string), and that apparently is a limitation of Swift 3.  The new model for collections and indices is discussed [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md).

---

If you want to store the ranges in an array and call `.count` and `.last` on them, you can convert the `Range<Index>` to a `CountableRange<Int>` while you still have access to the collection:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let myRange = str.range(of: "Hello")!

let lb = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: myRange.lowerBound) as Int
let ub = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: myRange.upperBound) as Int

let newRange = lb..<ub
newRange.count  // 5
newRange.last   // 4
```

Comment: Now imagine you have arrays of the ranges and you need the count for these ranges

Comment: The `as Int` cast is not necessary. `String.IndexDistance` is a type alias for `Int`.

Comment: @MartinR, yeah, that's why `as` succeeds.  I just wanted to be able to option click on `newRange` and see `CountableRange<Int>` instead of `CountableRange<IndexDistance>`.